# Intermittent Missing Resources Xamarin

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, android-resources

I have several solutions where I would say about 20% of the time I get a resource not found exception like the following during run-time.

```
 android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Unable to find resource ID #0x7f080007
```

Usually, I can temporarily fix the issue by cleaning the solution and restarting visual studio and then rebuilding. The resource isn't always the same between builds. Sometimes it is a  textview other times it is a drawable etc.

Note, the projects always builds fine, the error is always an exception thrown at runtime.

Has anyone else experienced something like this? Any advise on how I can debug the issue? I've done things like make sure resources don't contain forbidden characters etc.

Below is an abbreviated copy of the version information in my Help -> About Microsoft Visual studio window.

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2017 
Version 15.6.7
VisualStudio.15.Release/15.6.7+27428.2043
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.7.03056

Installed Version: Community

...

Visual Studio extension to enable development for Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android.
Xamarin   4.9.0.753 (f0f46392f)

Xamarin Designer   4.10.96 (a702a9ceb)
Visual Studio extension to enable Xamarin Designer tools in Visual Studio.

Xamarin.Android SDK   8.2.0.16 (HEAD/a78295902)
Xamarin.Android Reference Assemblies and MSBuild support.

Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Mac SDK   11.9.1.24 (f62de47)
Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Mac Reference Assemblies and MSBuild support.
```

Thanks!

Comment: Seem it many times ;-( What version of Xamarin.Android are you using?

Comment: I think that only solution first clean project and then run.

Comment: Thanks for your assistance @SushiHangover. My question has been updated with my visual studio 
 / xamarin version information.

Comment: @SushiHangover, I'm on pins and needles. I'm using a very recent version of Xamarin.Android (https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/android/xamarin.android_8/), is an upgrade going to fix this? Or is there something else that can be done?